# Can I modify external statment on my template?

Tags: angularjs, templates

My website follow the following template:

```
<html lang="fr" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"><title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <navbar>
            // My menu and other links
        </navbar>
        <section role="main" ng-controller="car-controller">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="car in car">
                    {{car.state}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>  
        // Footer
    </body>
</html>
```

All my different pages should have a different main section with a different controller to manage them.

My question is : how can I update my `{{title}}` statment from all my controllers like the `car-controller` on this exemple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the document title from inside the controllers by injecting [`$window`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24window) or [`$document`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24document), without binding any value to it.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('car-controller', function($scope, $window){
        $window.document.title = "Title from Car Controller";
});
```

You can move the logic to a callable function if required and this can be done for all the controllers you are planning to use for each section.